# CSS: Mantener el estilo al hacer un display: inline-block

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Tengo una tabla en la cual puedo arrastrar filas haciendo drag and drop.

Para romper algunas palabras utilizo el `word-wrap:break-word;`y el `display:inline-block` para que funcione en navegadores como Chrome.

El estilo, al arrastrar una fila la cual tiene el estilo aplicado de display:inline-block cambia y se ve mal.

Dejo un JSFiddle para que se pueda testear. (La segunda fila es la que va mal).

https://jsfiddle.net/w52m5ggb/6/

Se ve bien: (fila no afectada por el inline-block)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se ve mal: (fila afectada por el inline-block)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cual es el error exactamente? No esta claro cual es tu problema.

Comment: Prueba a arrastrar abajo o arriba la fila que contiene el campo Slugggggg, ahí veras el problema con los estilos @Einer

Comment: Lo unico que noto es que las letras se solapan con la imagen. Ese es el problema?

Comment: @Einer Puedes revisar ahora la pregunta, con las imagenes lo notaras.

Comment: @blonfu puedes revisar la pregunta, esta actualizada con imagenes.

Comment: Prueba a arrastrar alguna @blonfu, si arrastras la segunda te pasara eso.

Comment: @LluísPuigFerrer igual a mi.

Comment: Creo que ya te entendi. Te refieres que los estilos cambian mientras se esta efectuando el drag pero una vez lo sueltas, se ve bien. CIerto?

Comment: Exacto @Einer, mientras hago el drag se ve mal pero al hacer el drop se queda bien.

Comment: @blonfu incluso cuando haces el drag, ves las tres igual?

Comment: En el contexto de tu ejemplo, [la unica solucion que veo es eliminar al regla `display:inline-block` y dejar que texto ocupe tanto espacio necesite](http://jsbin.com/dimaxadefo/edit?html,css,output). Al no tener [espacio, la propiedad `word-wrap:break-word` no funciona, si se se le agregara un espacio, funcionaria perfecto](http://jsbin.com/kugobiqaxo/edit?html,output).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes probar a aplicar el estilo al párrafo en lugar de a la celda:

```js
$("#tabs").tabs();

$("#tabs ul li a").droppable({
    hoverClass: "drophover",
    tolerance: "pointer",
    drop: function(e, ui) {
        var tabdiv = $(this).attr("href");
        $(tabdiv + " table tr:last").after("<tr>" + ui.draggable.html() + "</tr>");
        ui.draggable.remove();
    }
});

$("#tbodyproject").sortable({
    items: "> tr",
    appendTo: "parent",
    helper: "clone",
    update: function( event, ui ) {
        let newOrder = $(this).sortable('toArray');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:'/admin/projects/updateOrder',
            data: {ids: newOrder}
        })
       .done(function( msg ) {
        location.reload();        
       });
    }
}).disableSelection();
```

```css
img {
  width: 100px;
  
}
td.name{
  overflow: hidden;
}
td.name p{
  display:inline-block;
  word-wrap:word;
  width:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="tabs">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div id="table1">
              <table class="table">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th class="thcenter"><!--<a href="{{route('admin.projects.order', ['field' => 'id','order' => 'asc'])}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up" id="orderByIdAsc"></span></a>-->ID<!--<a href="{{route('admin.projects.order', ['field' => 'id','order' => 'desc'])}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down" id="orderByIdDesc"></span></a>--></th>
                    <th class="thcenter"><!--<a href="{{route('admin.projects.order', ['field' => 'slug','order' => 'asc'])}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up" id="orderBySlugAsc"></span></a>-->Visible<!--<a href="{{route('admin.projects.order',['field' => 'slug','order' => 'desc'])}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down" id="orderBySlugDown"></span></a>--></th>
                    <th><!--<a href="{{route('admin.projects.order', ['field' => 'order','order' => 'asc'])}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up" id="orderByOrderAsc"></span></a>-->Nombre<!--<a href="{{route('admin.projects.order', ['field' => 'order','order' => 'desc'])}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down" id="orderByOrderDesc"></span></a>--></th>
                    <th>Header</th>
                    <th>Home</th>
                    <th class="thcenter"><!--<a href="{{route('admin.projects.order', ['field' => 'public','order' => 'asc'])}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up" id="orderByPublicAsc"></span></a>-->Orden<!--<a href="{{route('admin.projects.order', ['field' => 'public','order' => 'desc'])}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down" id="orderByPublicDesc"></span></a>--></th>
                    <th><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span>Acciones</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody id="tbodyproject"> 
                    <tr id="id1" class="trdrag">
                      <td class="idrow tdcenter"><p id="margindata">1</p></td>
                      <td class="tdcenter"> 
                        <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true" id="margindata"></i>  
                      </td>
                      <td><p id="margindata">Slug</p></td>
                      <td><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="sizeheader"></td>
                      <td><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="sizehome"></td>
                      <td class="tdcenter"><p id="margindata">Order 1</p></td>
                        <td>
                      <form method="POST" action="{{route('admin.projects.destroy',$project->id)}}" onsubmit="return ConfirmarBorrar()">
                    
                          <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" id="margindata">Edit</a> 
                          <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="margindata">
                          <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="Token 1">Delete
                          </form>
                      </td>
                      
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="id2" class="trdrag">
                      <td class="idrow tdcenter"><p id="margindata">2</p></td>
                      <td class="tdcenter"> 
                        <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true" id="margindata"></i>  
                      </td>
                      <td class="name"><p id="margindata">Slugggggggggggg</p></td>
                      <td><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="sizeheader"></td>
                      <td><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="sizehome"></td>
                      <td class="tdcenter"><p id="margindata">Order 2</p></td>
                            <td>
                      <form method="POST" action="{{route('admin.projects.destroy',$project->id)}}" onsubmit="return ConfirmarBorrar()">
                          <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" id="margindata">Edit</a> 
                          <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="margindata">
                          <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="Token 2">Delete
                      </form>
                             </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="id3" class="trdrag">
                      <td class="idrow tdcenter"><p id="margindata">3</p></td>
                      <td class="tdcenter"> 
                        <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true" id="margindata"></i>  
                      </td>
                      <td><p id="margindata">Slug</p></td>
                      <td><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="sizeheader"></td>
                      <td><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="sizehome"></td>
                      <td class="tdcenter"><p id="margindata">Order 3</p></td>
                       <td>
                      <form method="POST" action="{{route('admin.projects.destroy',$project->id)}}" onsubmit="return ConfirmarBorrar()">
                          <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" id="margindata">Edit</a> 
                          <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="margindata">
                          <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="Token 3">Delete
                      </form>
                     </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
              <br><br>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Buena idea, el problema es que se solapan algunas letras, alguna manera para corregirlo?

Comment: Si no te importa que no se muestren puedes ocultarlas con un `overflow: hidden`. He modificado el ejemplo para mostrar cómo.

Comment: Así esta mejor, pero lo interesante sería que se viera todo el slug al hacer el drag.

Answer (score 2):

En el contexto de tu ejemplo, la unica solucion que veo es eliminar al regla `display:inline-block` y dejar que texto ocupe tanto espacio necesite:

```js
$("#tabs").tabs();

$("#tabs ul li a").droppable({
    hoverClass: "drophover",
    tolerance: "pointer",
    drop: function(e, ui) {
        var tabdiv = $(this).attr("href");
        $(tabdiv + " table tr:last").after("<tr>" + ui.draggable.html() + "</tr>");
        ui.draggable.remove();
    }
});

$("#tbodyproject").sortable({
    items: "> tr",
    appendTo: "parent",
    helper: "clone",
    update: function( event, ui ) {
        let newOrder = $(this).sortable('toArray');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:'/admin/projects/updateOrder',
            data: {ids: newOrder}
        })
       .done(function( msg ) {
        //location.reload();        
       });
    }
}).disableSelection();
```

```css
img {
  width: 100px;
  
}
.name{

  word-wrap:break-word;
  width:60px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script><div id="tabs">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div id="table1">
              <table class="table">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th class="thcenter"><!--<a href="{{route('admin.projects.order', ['field' => 'id','order' => 'asc'])}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up" id="orderByIdAsc"></span></a>-->ID<!--<a href="{{route('admin.projects.order', ['field' => 'id','order' => 'desc'])}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down" id="orderByIdDesc"></span></a>--></th>
                    <th class="thcenter"><!--<a href="{{route('admin.projects.order', ['field' => 'slug','order' => 'asc'])}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up" id="orderBySlugAsc"></span></a>-->Visible<!--<a href="{{route('admin.projects.order',['field' => 'slug','order' => 'desc'])}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down" id="orderBySlugDown"></span></a>--></th>
                    <th><!--<a href="{{route('admin.projects.order', ['field' => 'order','order' => 'asc'])}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up" id="orderByOrderAsc"></span></a>-->Nombre<!--<a href="{{route('admin.projects.order', ['field' => 'order','order' => 'desc'])}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down" id="orderByOrderDesc"></span></a>--></th>
                    <th>Header</th>
                    <th>Home</th>
                    <th class="thcenter"><!--<a href="{{route('admin.projects.order', ['field' => 'public','order' => 'asc'])}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up" id="orderByPublicAsc"></span></a>-->Orden<!--<a href="{{route('admin.projects.order', ['field' => 'public','order' => 'desc'])}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down" id="orderByPublicDesc"></span></a>--></th>
                    <th><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span>Acciones</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody id="tbodyproject"> 
                    <tr id="id1" class="trdrag">
                      <td class="idrow tdcenter"><p id="margindata">1</p></td>
                      <td class="tdcenter"> 
                        <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true" id="margindata"></i>  
                      </td>
                      <td><p id="margindata">Slug</p></td>
                      <td><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="sizeheader"></td>
                      <td><img src="http://via.plom/350x150" class="sizehome"></td>
                      <td class="tdcenter"><p id="margindata">Order 1</p></td>
                        <td>
                      <form method="POST" action="{{route('admin.projects.destroy',$project->id)}}" onsubmit="return ConfirmarBorrar()">
                    
                          <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" id="margindata">Edit</a> 
                          <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="margindata">
                          <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="Token 1">Delete
                          </form>
                      </td>
                      
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="id2" class="trdrag">
                      <td class="idrow tdcenter"><p id="margindata">2</p></td>
                      <td class="tdcenter"> 
                        <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true" id="margindata"></i>  
                      </td>

                      <td class="name" width="50px"><p id="margindata">Slugggggggggggg</p></td>
                             
                      <td><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="sizeheader"></td>
                      <td><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="sizehome"></td>
                      <td class="tdcenter"><p id="margindata">Order 2</p></td>
                            <td>
                      <form method="POST" action="{{route('admin.projects.destroy',$project->id)}}" onsubmit="return ConfirmarBorrar()">
                          <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" id="margindata">Edit</a> 
                          <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="margindata">
                          <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="Token 2">Delete
                      </form>
                             </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="id3" class="trdrag">
                      <td class="idrow tdcenter"><p id="margindata">3</p></td>
                      <td class="tdcenter"> 
                        <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true" id="margindata"></i>  
                      </td>
                      <td><p id="margindata">Slug</p></td>
                      <td><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="sizeheader"></td>
                      <td><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="sizehome"></td>
                      <td class="tdcenter"><p id="margindata">Order 3</p></td>
                       <td>
                      <form method="POST" action="{{route('admin.projects.destroy',$project->id)}}" onsubmit="return ConfirmarBorrar()">
                          <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" id="margindata">Edit</a> 
                          <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="margindata">
                          <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="Token 3">Delete
                      </form>
                     </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
              <br><br>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Al texto **Slugggggggggggg** no tener espacio, la propiedad `word-wrap:break-word` no surte ningun efecto, ahora bien si se le agregara siquiera un espacio funcionaria perfecto:

```js
$("#tabs").tabs();

$("#tabs ul li a").droppable({
    hoverClass: "drophover",
    tolerance: "pointer",
    drop: function(e, ui) {
        var tabdiv = $(this).attr("href");
        $(tabdiv + " table tr:last").after("<tr>" + ui.draggable.html() + "</tr>");
        ui.draggable.remove();
    }
});

$("#tbodyproject").sortable({
    items: "> tr",
    appendTo: "parent",
    helper: "clone",
    update: function( event, ui ) {
        let newOrder = $(this).sortable('toArray');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:'/admin/projects/updateOrder',
            data: {ids: newOrder}
        })
       .done(function( msg ) {
        //location.reload();        
       });
    }
}).disableSelection();
```

```css
img {
  width: 100px;
  
}
.name{

  word-wrap:break-word;
  width:60px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script><div id="tabs">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div id="table1">
              <table class="table">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th class="thcenter"><!--<a href="{{route('admin.projects.order', ['field' => 'id','order' => 'asc'])}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up" id="orderByIdAsc"></span></a>-->ID<!--<a href="{{route('admin.projects.order', ['field' => 'id','order' => 'desc'])}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down" id="orderByIdDesc"></span></a>--></th>
                    <th class="thcenter"><!--<a href="{{route('admin.projects.order', ['field' => 'slug','order' => 'asc'])}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up" id="orderBySlugAsc"></span></a>-->Visible<!--<a href="{{route('admin.projects.order',['field' => 'slug','order' => 'desc'])}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down" id="orderBySlugDown"></span></a>--></th>
                    <th><!--<a href="{{route('admin.projects.order', ['field' => 'order','order' => 'asc'])}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up" id="orderByOrderAsc"></span></a>-->Nombre<!--<a href="{{route('admin.projects.order', ['field' => 'order','order' => 'desc'])}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down" id="orderByOrderDesc"></span></a>--></th>
                    <th>Header</th>
                    <th>Home</th>
                    <th class="thcenter"><!--<a href="{{route('admin.projects.order', ['field' => 'public','order' => 'asc'])}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up" id="orderByPublicAsc"></span></a>-->Orden<!--<a href="{{route('admin.projects.order', ['field' => 'public','order' => 'desc'])}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down" id="orderByPublicDesc"></span></a>--></th>
                    <th><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span>Acciones</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody id="tbodyproject"> 
                    <tr id="id1" class="trdrag">
                      <td class="idrow tdcenter"><p id="margindata">1</p></td>
                      <td class="tdcenter"> 
                        <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true" id="margindata"></i>  
                      </td>
                      <td><p id="margindata">Slug</p></td>
                      <td><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="sizeheader"></td>
                      <td><img src="http://via.plom/350x150" class="sizehome"></td>
                      <td class="tdcenter"><p id="margindata">Order 1</p></td>
                        <td>
                      <form method="POST" action="{{route('admin.projects.destroy',$project->id)}}" onsubmit="return ConfirmarBorrar()">
                    
                          <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" id="margindata">Edit</a> 
                          <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="margindata">
                          <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="Token 1">Delete
                          </form>
                      </td>
                      
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="id2" class="trdrag">
                      <td class="idrow tdcenter"><p id="margindata">2</p></td>
                      <td class="tdcenter"> 
                        <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true" id="margindata"></i>  
                      </td>
                      
                      
                      <!--AQUI LE DI UN ESPACIO Y SE VE PERFECTAMENTE CUANDO SE HACE DRAG-->
                      <td class="name" width="50px"><p id="margindata">Sluggggg ggggggg</p></td>
                      
                      
                      
                      <td><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="sizeheader"></td>
                      <td><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="sizehome"></td>
                      <td class="tdcenter"><p id="margindata">Order 2</p></td>
                            <td>
                      <form method="POST" action="{{route('admin.projects.destroy',$project->id)}}" onsubmit="return ConfirmarBorrar()">
                          <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" id="margindata">Edit</a> 
                          <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="margindata">
                          <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="Token 2">Delete
                      </form>
                             </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="id3" class="trdrag">
                      <td class="idrow tdcenter"><p id="margindata">3</p></td>
                      <td class="tdcenter"> 
                        <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true" id="margindata"></i>  
                      </td>
                      <td><p id="margindata">Slug</p></td>
                      <td><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="sizeheader"></td>
                      <td><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="sizehome"></td>
                      <td class="tdcenter"><p id="margindata">Order 3</p></td>
                       <td>
                      <form method="POST" action="{{route('admin.projects.destroy',$project->id)}}" onsubmit="return ConfirmarBorrar()">
                          <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" id="margindata">Edit</a> 
                          <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="margindata">
                          <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="Token 3">Delete
                      </form>
                     </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
              <br><br>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Por lo que queda a tu decisión sobre que forma mas te conviene.

Comment: Si puedes ponme el enlace a los JSFiddle para tocar el codigo

Comment: Tengo los 2 ejemplos en jsbin. [Clic sobre este link para el ejemplo con el espacio en el texto](http://jsbin.com/kugobiqaxo/edit?output) y clic sobre [este para  el ejemplo sin la regla css](http://jsbin.com/dimaxadefo/edit?output)

Comment: Tus ejemplos son de ayuda, pero realmente no solucionan mi problema. Con el display inline-block consigo fragmentar una frase sin espacios, que es el objetivo numero 1, y después al hacer el drag se tendría que mantener el estilo como dice el compañero @Asiervillanueva

Answer (score 1):

eso pasa por que `word` no es un valor válido para la propiedad `word-wrap`, prueba colocando el siguiente valor:

```
word-wrap: break-word
```

Espero te sirva, saludos !

Comment: Ese no era el error, todo y que se me había olvidado ponerlo bien en el JSFiddle, gracias!

Comment: Acabo de ver la edición que hiciste a tu pregunta, que navegador estas usando ? la verdad en mi Google Chrome muevo las filas a mi antojo y ninguna se daña como muestras en tus imágenes

Comment: Uso chrome, y no le aplico el estilo al tr, si no al td.

Comment: Chrome en un MAC.